# Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My code:

```
module.exports = async (client, message) => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('815676619955503124');
    setInterval(() => {
        const channelgp = guild.channels.cache.get('815856763114487808');
        let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('815855967773786113');
        console.log(`${goldpiston.size} person with this role`);
        channelgp.setName(`gold piston owner: ${goldpiston.toLocal}`);
        console.log('Refreshing...');
    }, 5000); }
```

And the error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscordBot\counters\roles-counter.js:7
        let goldpiston = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members;
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\user\Desktop\DiscordBot\counters\roles-counter.js:7:34)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

At the begining the code was for checking who's online. I changed it to see who has the role.

Comment: The error means that `message` is `undefined`. How are you calling the function? Do you pass a message to it?

Comment: seems to be a handler error, could you post your handler code?

Answer (score 0):

No I was just calling only client.
This is main.js it is in the root folder. Previous code is in "counter" folder.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const memberCounter = require('./counters/member-counter');
const rolesCounter = require('./counters/roles-counter');
 
const prefix = '$';
 
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('2c5t is online!');
    memberCounter(client);
    rolesCounter(client);
})
 
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'author')
    {
        message.channel.send('Author is onhq');
        console.log('Command used!');
    }
})
 
client.login('ODE1NjYzMDkzMTU2ODA2NjY2.YDvrcw.5XhiBf4SGFyU1hQkye152f2hmdc');
```